# Verify physical item with pgp key online by decrypting the private key

Tags: cryptography, verify, openpgp

I want to sell some of my collectable items that I have been collecting over the years. But I don't want to just sell it, I want to add a QR code to the item (back of the painting, on the deck of cards etc.) and have that link to a website that can verify the item is the real thing.

I was thinking of using pgp-keys (public/private) to verify the item.

Is there already a way to do this or would I have to write something to decrypt the private key for validation? What language would be able to do this, can I do it in python?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you are actually seeking to do.
You could embed a message that you sign with your private key, which can then be verified to be authentic with your public key.
If you want the message to be encrypted, you will need to pass a private key to the buyer and encrypt the message with the corresponding public key.

Generally, you don't need the private key unless you are doing encryption or signing. There are libraries for PGP in essentially all programming languages, python has `python-gnupg` for this.